# How get row index of <ace:dataTable> in every row?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-3

In searching I found that we can do something with `rowStateVar` or `rowIndex` attributes of `<ace:datatable>`, but how?

I tried using `<h:outputText value="#{myDataTableVar.rowIndex}">` but it shows an error message that `myDataTableVar` has no property `rowIndex`.

Comment: If you don't want to know about icefaces datatable, then review your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a component library independent way, just use [`UIData#getRowIndex()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#getRowIndex%28%29) as every component library specific datatable extends from this base component.

In the below example, `x:` can be anything: standard JSF `h:`, ICEfaces `ice:` or `ace:`, PrimeFaces `p:`, RichFaces `rich:`, etc.

```
<x:dataTable binding="#{table}" ...>
    <x:column>#{table.rowIndex}</x:column>
</x:dataTable>
```

Note: the `binding="#{table}"` is as-is! You don't need to bind it to some managed bean property.

Comment: I'm unable to see how and why "using ajax" would form a problem in this. Either you're misunderstanding the real problem, or there's more at matter in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution `<ace:datatable id='tbl' rowIndexVar="row">` and then just print like that `<h:outputtext value="#{row}">`
Very simple

Comment: keep in mind this can be used when we using datatable of ace created by xmlns:ace="http://www.icefaces.org/icefaces/components"

Answer (score 1):

First, set varStatus:

```
<ice:dataTable varStatus="status">
```

An then, inside that dataTable, use:

```
#{status.index}
```

Comment: Always read question carefully and completly and then answer.I have mentioned that that I want to know usage of "rowStateVar" as I am using aceface's datatable.Your answer is right but for icefaces datatable, because we havn't any "varStatus" attribute in ace:datatable ...

Comment: @William There is no way on earth that your question is **not** about **icefaces** datatable. You clearly stated that when you said _"while iterating datatable of icefaces"_, and tagget the question with `icefaces` and `icefaces-3`. Right now `ace` can only be considered a typo. If you don't want to know about icefaces datatable, then review your question, because it can not be interpreted in any other way.

Comment: there is no tag for ace.Anyway i found the solution